# Which font can show such charaters described in the post clearly?

Tags: vim, character, appearance

Set the font for my vim with `DejaVu Sans Mono Book`.Edit a file `character.txt` encoding with `utf-8` which contain five characters 
`hyphen-minus`,`hyphen`,`en dash`,`em dash`,`minus`,each character contains one line.

```
xxd character.txt
00000000: 2d0a e280 900a e280 930a e280 940a e288  -...............
00000010: 920a 0a
```

Name all the characters according to such webpage:

[hyphen-minus](http://www.unicode-symbol.com/u/002d.html)
[hyphen](http://www.unicode-symbol.com/u/2010.html)
[en dash](http://www.unicode-symbol.com/u/2013.html)
[emdash](http://www.unicode-symbol.com/u/2014.html)
[minus](http://www.unicode-symbol.com/u/2212.html)

Show them in my vim with `DejaVu Sans Mono Book` font.

[image]

It is hard to distinguish between `hyphen-minus` and `hyphen`,to distinguish between `en dash` and `em dash`  and `minus`.
Could you introduce me a font which can show the five characters clearly in vim?

Answer (score 0):

Vim is a text editor designed to use *monospaced* fonts. And it's a problem for any monospaced font: it's hard to make about ten "horizontal lines" clearly distinguishable from each other when the character width is so much limited.

Personally, I suggest to use Inconsolata font. But you'd better try yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own syntax highlighting for this case. Look up for `digraphs` in Vim. In docs, I could find hyphen(-1), en dash(-N), em dash(-M) and minus(-2).

To type these characters:

1. Go in insert mode
2. Do `Ctrl+k`
3. Type respective symbols in the parenthesis above.

For e.g., to print endash, in insert mode do `Ctrl+k`. It will show a `?`. Then type `-N` (case sensitive).

For highlighting those characters you can use `:syn match` and `:highlight`

`:syn match` to define the group and `:highlight` to change the colors of the defined group. Refer to docs for more details: `:help syn-match` and `:help highlight`.